# How is the index locked during transaction updates?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, indexing, b-tree

I am confused about the locking in InnoDB.
I know that it locks at a row level but as far as I have understood it also locks the index.
But how exactly is the index locked?
E.g. for the clustered index: Is the leaf that holds the row locked or all the ancestors of that leaf. Up to which level?

Comment: Are you asking out of curiosity, or did you face an actual issue that lead to this question?

Comment: @RandomSeed:I don't have an actual problem. But I am interested in understanding this

Answer (score 0):

A (conceptual) record-level lock is in fact a (physical) lock on an index record.

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html) (emphasis mine):

> InnoDB has several types of record-level locks including record locks, gap locks, and next-key locks. (...)
>
> - Record lock: This is a lock **on an index record**.
> - Gap lock: This is a lock on a gap **between index records**
> - Next-key lock: This is a combination of a record **lock on the index record** and a gap lock on the gap **before the index record**.

Therefore whatever is said about row-level locking actually refers to index locks.

I have never seen lower-level information about the implementation details, the gory details lore in the source code, I am afraid...